# Formatting Gtk.SpinButton's output does not work for single mouse clicks

Tags: javascript, gtk, gjs

I'm trying to format the output of `Gtk.SpinButton` in GJS. The goal for now is to simply prepend a string "prefix" to SpinButton's text.

Here's a barebone implementation:

```
#!/usr/bin/gjs

imports.gi.versions.Gtk = "3.0";

const { Gtk } = imports.gi;

Gtk.init(null);

let window = new Gtk.Window();
let adjustment = Gtk.Adjustment.new(0, 0, 10, 1, 0, 0);
let spinButton = new Gtk.SpinButton();

spinButton.adjustment = adjustment;
spinButton.wrap = true;
spinButton.width_chars = 10;

window.add(spinButton);

spinButton.connect('output', formatOutput);
spinButton.connect('value-changed', reportChange);

function formatOutput(button) {
    let prefixed = `prefix${button.adjustment.value}`;
    button.set_text(prefixed);
    return true;
}

function reportChange(button) {
    log(`value changed ${button.value}`);
}

window.show_all();

window.connect('destroy', Gtk.main_quit);

Gtk.main();
```

[As suggested by the documentation](https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/gtk30~3.24.18/gtk.spinbutton#signal-output), I tap into `Gtk.SpinButton`'s `output` signal.

The code above works fine when I:

1. Scroll on the `Gtk.SpinButton` with mouse wheel
2. Click and hold `Gtk.SpinButton`'s -/+ buttons with mouse left button

However, single clicks on -/+ buttons do not change the value by more than two increments (e.g. if initial value is 0 and `step-size` is 1, incrementing with single clicks will only reach 1 (or -1 in other direction) and stop there).

Furthermore, it seems that whenever the `output` signal is connected (even if it merely returns `true`), a single click fires the `value-changed` signal twice: SpinButton's value is first set to zero and then incremented. The result is that, for single clicks, the value of the `Gtk.SpinButton` is stuck at the value `0+increment` or `0-increment`. I have no clue how to explain this behavior.. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems that we also need to connect to Gtk.SpinButton's input signal (https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/gtk30~3.24.18/gtk.spinbutton#signal-input), which we cannot handle because it has a GPointer as one of it's parameters. Ultimately, I wanted to use Gtk.SpinButton for time of the day selection, but it doesn't seem to be possible with GJS. At least for now.